# VHDL Generic component declaration syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl

I am having a simple generic single clock ram, and it has multiple generic values. However, I am getting a syntax error while declaring it. 
The full structure of the code is:

```
entity main is
Port ( 
-- components
);
end main;


architecture Behavioral of main is
component xilinx_simple_dual_port_1_clock_ram is 
    generic (
    RAM_WIDTH : integer, --< what is wrong here?
    RAM_DEPTH : integer,
    RAM_PERFORMANCE : string,
    INIT_FILE : string
    );
port 
    (
    addra : in std_logic_vector(clogb2(RAM_DEPTH)-1) downto 0);
    addrb : in std_logic_vector(clogb2(RAM_DEPTH)-1) downto 0); 
    dina  : in std_logic_vector(RAM_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    clka  : in std_logic;
    wea   : in std_logic;
    enb   : in std_logic;
    rstb  : in std_logic;
    regceb: in std_logic;
    doutb : out std_logic_vector(RAM_WIDTH-1 downto 0)
    );

    end component;

begin
ramA: xilinx_simple_dual_port_1_clock_ram
     generic map (
     RAM_WIDTH => 18,
     RAM_DEPTH => 1024,
     RAM_PERFORMANCE => "HIGH_PERFORMANCE",
     INIT_FILE => "" 
    )
      port map  (
     addra  => addra, 
     addrb  => addrb, 
     dina   => dina,  
     clka   => clka,  
     wea    => wea,   
     enb    => enb,   
     rsta   => rsta,  
     regceb => regceb,
     doutb  => doutb 
    );
```

The other signals have been taken care of, including the port mapping to the bram module. I am getting a syntax error in the generic declaration.

Comment: Also there was an extra bracket on the addra and addrb, which I noticed later.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. You can't have an empty interface list for entity main, the separator for generic interface declarations should be a ';' , you have too many closing parens in addra and addrb (remove those after the 1s), you don't declare the actual signals for port map and you're missing a context clause (ieee; ieee.std_logic_1164.all;) There's no clog2b visible. You mislabeled actual rstb rsta in the ramA port map. Et Voila! - no syntax error. There is no requirement for a default value unless there is no actual provided for your generics. Provide the entire error message(s) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give a generic a default value:

```
RAM_WIDTH : integer := 16;
--                       ^
```

Also use `;` not `,`

Comment: Yes I added that too, but it is still having a syntax error. `generic (
 RAM_WIDTH : integer := 16,
 RAM_DEPTH : integer := 1024,
 RAM_PERFORMANCE : string := "LOW_LATENCY",
 INIT_FILE : string := ""
);`

Comment: You do not have to give a generic a default value. The problem is the comma.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.2 Generic clauses "The value of a generic constant may be specified by the corresponding actual in a generic association list. If no such actual is specified for a given formal generic constant (either because the formal generic is unassociated or because the actual is **open**), and if a default expression is specified for that generic, the value of this expression is the value of the generic. It is an error if no actual is specified for a given formal generic constant and no default expression is present in the corresponding interface element."

Comment: That clause only applies to entity not component because in a component the value is given by the generic association list (aka generic map)